# threads presentation in pstree

Tags: process, pstree

I read manual of command `tree` and confused about  threads

```
   Child threads of a process are found under the parent process and are shown with the process name  in  curly  braces,
   e.g.

       icecast2---13*[{icecast2}]
```

Does it mean that process icecast has 13 threads?

Comment: Yes, the [pstree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pstree.1.html)  man page is right about that ;-)

Comment: @SimonSudler You may want to post an answer, and please quote the part of the manual to which you're referring here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [pstree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pstree.1.html) shows the number of threads create by a process:

> Child threads of a process are found under the parent  process  and  are  shown  with  the
>   process name in curly braces

In the [icecast2](http://icecast.org/) case, the `threadpool` option was removed from the [configuration](https://github.com/xiph/Icecast-Server/blob/v2.4.3/ChangeLog) in current versions.

> 2014-07-23 16:55:57  dm8tbr
>
> - removed threadpool from example config
>     it is long gone and unused

so the amount of threads cannot be controlled by the configuration.

Comment: @sergiy-kolodyazhnyy just for you ;-)